# Magento 2: Extend Magento Customer, add new label and content

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I'm new to magento 2. I'm having problem on creating a *new label in the customer dashboard area* and add a content with it.

My question is how to create a label with content. How should be the correct process for it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Attached is the screenshots for my desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For add a link on  Customer navigation, you need to

add new below code at **customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-resource-center-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">[YourUrl]</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Resouce Center</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Great. True coder. +1 from me. :P